# How to refresh the WordPress home page without user noticing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I would like to refresh the home page every X sec. I found this solution:

1. Install Auto Refresh Single Page plugin
2. Insert to header.php the lines:

```php
if (is_front_page()) {
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="5">' ;
}
```

It refreshes the page but I notice that the page is reloaded. I would like it to happen smoothly. I don't want the refresh to make the page disappear for milliseconds. I want to refresh without the user noticing.

I have a page build with Wordpress. This page have few divs. Part of them list post type - and I need i to updated in case a new post submitted. Some divs need to change according to time of the day or the week and display different data. The page need to show all the time like a TV and information should be update automatically with no human touch. I tried to use ajax, but I don't know how to point it to reload specific div that built from Wordpress - I have no URL for specific div.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It would be really annoying for your users. That said, you can't 'refresh smoothly'. It sounds like AJAX or websockets would be a much better solution in that case.

Comment: To my knowledge this isn't really do-able. Your best bet would be as the guy said above AJAX or websockets or some such. 

I've done something somewhat similar using React to update the front end if changes are found, e.g. new row in a database adding a row to a table. without refreshing the whole page, but without knowing what you're wanting to do it's impossible to tell if this would work for you.

Comment: I add to my question more details

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
if (is_front_page()) {
    ?>
    <script>
      setTimeout(function() { window.location = ""; }, 1000); //1 sec = 1000
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read your question, And as i thinking, you want update your posts on users homepage without any reloading. This can be done using "AJAX PHP". You should find plugins that uses "AJAX PHP" or "AJAX JAVASCRIPT".I hope this would be useful for you.

Comment: how can I use ajax to reload widget in Wordpress? it not a regular url and not a php file?